# How to use PropertyGroupItem

Tags: scripting, properties, documentation

I was browsing the docs when I ran into something interesting: `bpy.types.propertyGroupItem`

This is what the doc says about it:

> Property that stores arbitrary, user defined properties

I did a little digging around but couldn't find anything else about it. It sounds very interesting but I have absolutely no idea how to use it. Could someone give an explanation of what this is and when to use it?

Comment: example is in the [DOC](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/bpy.types.PropertyGroup.html?highlight=propertygroupitem)

Comment: Instances of `MyPropertyGroup` as seen in that example can store two properties, `custom_1` and `custom_2`. The instances of these properties are PropertyGroupItems. You don't use that type however, it's handled internally. See here for properties in general: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.props.html

Comment: @CoDEmanX That makes a lot of sense, thanks!